# Cisco IP Communicator - Send commands/Auto Dial

Tags: voip, cisco

Does anyone know if I can somehow send commands to Cisco IP Communicator software?

Something simple like

```
1) Send Number
2) Dial Number
```

Presuming the software is already open and running on my machine.

Or could a dirty copy and paste workaround work.

```
1) Copy Number into Clipboard
2) Bring Cisco IP Communicator to front
3) Paste number
4) Press enter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if it possible, but if you want to make a dial you can do it with TAPI3 or JTAPI program, you just need an application user.
Jump start [HERE](https://developer.cisco.com/site/tapi/overview/)